# Should the job ads bar be brought to law stackexchange

Tags: discussion, user-interface

Stackexchange is home to many different communities, full of experts in their fields. one of the cooler features in the stackexchange community is the jobs side-bar like the one shown on stackoverflow(a community of coders), this side-bar displays job listings, their locations, and the skill sets required to work the job. This allows community experts to display their talents in the real world and make a living doing what they're great at.

[image]

Adding this feature to law.stackexchange.com would allow for future employers to review your record of what you've done on the site.

Should job ads be integrated into law stackexchange?

Comment: Related on MSE: [Job posting on other Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/324671)

Comment: +1 to [Andrew's link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/324671/241697): Job ads are unique to StackOverflow.  Since presently the question of whether they can or should be implemented on *any other* Stack Exchange is on SE Meta, I would recommend this request be raised there.

Comment: For the record, I suspect that if SE wanted to do this, your opinion (and the opinion of the users below the line) would count for precisely zero

Comment: @Richard, I see where you're coming from, but we don't have the "feature-request" tag not to use it.

Answer (score 2):

> Should job ads be integrated into law stackexchange?

I can imagine this could mean revenues to SE and I have nothing against that, but trying to sell this as a benefit to users just doesn't cut it.

> Adding this feature to law.stackexchange.com would allow for future employers to review your record of what you've done on the site.

Allowing recruiters to advertise job positions is different than facilitating employers' screening process.

I see no added value in adding the feature you suggest. Interested candidates can always include a few SE links (and/or the candidate's online IDs, if need be) in their resume or cover letters for a prospective employer to review their record. That sort of screening is more effective than having a recruiter/employer phone-call the friends a candidate lists as his references.

Additionally, it is well known that the same job positions are posted simultaneously in multiple job search platforms: Indeed.com, monster.com, craigslist, Linkedin, as well as *niche* sites. Sometimes the multi-posting is done by the same recruiter, other times by multiple competing recruiters. Posting them also on SE is fine; it's just not really a "plus".

Answer (score 1):

> Should job ads be integrated into law stackexchange?

No. Why? Because unlike on stackoverflow which is recruiting people that demonstrate a skill set in coding regardless of background, the law is not just about a skill set or knowledge, but a profession requiring professional licensing and thus not well suited for this community.

Comment: Both the jobs listed actually don't require professional licensing in most states (Paralegal/ legal assistant).

Comment: @StephanS I suppose you're right, I need to rearticulate my point to more along the lines of for coding you just need to prove you are a rational person that can learn, legal work ussually want some form of formal training.